# 200 Amp exterior meter and disconnect with interior main panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Can I have an exterior 200A meter and disconnect with the 200A main panel in the interior some 20-30 ft. away? It has to meet California residential code.

I'm trying to avoid the cost of an exterior main panel in addition to a 200A interior sub-panel.

If so, what products should I look for for the exterior? I was thinking "meter socket with disconnect" but I can only find exterior panels.

Here is an elevation plan:
[image]

I currently have a 100A exterior panel at the meter which I need to upgrade to 200A but my contractor recommends having a panel in the interior hallway for convenience.

I can't add the panel close to the meter in the interior because of house configuration. It will have to be 20-30ft away.

Thanks.

Comment: A NEMA  3R  panel outside with a breaker would work there are a bunch of them I recommend one with extra positions so later if another sub to an out building is desirable it would be easy to add.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question: keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I've got this setup on my house, the meter base it separate from the main breaker, they are just next to each other, and then there is a feeder from the disconnect/breaker to the actual panel inside (80+ feet away). What you're looking for seems to be called "Outdoor Circuit Breaker Enclosure".

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Google words you are looking for are **meter main** or **meter main combination**.

As long as the wiring in your house is downstream of a main **breaker** (not merely disconnect), that is fine.  Remember since all the power from your service runs through it, you get to apply the  310.15(B)(7) derate of 83%; your wire only needs to be rated for 166A, not 200A.

This Article 310.15(B)(7) derate calculation replaces a table called 310.15(B)(7), and you will see that table all over the Web. The table is completely useless, and should be disregarded.